# Changing Windows 'hosts' file in guest OS under Parallels Desktop 6 on Mac

Tags: macos, parallels, hosts-file

I am running Windows 7 in a Parallels Desktop 6 on Mac.

On the mac, I use `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1 mysite
```

and it works fine; I can type `mysite` in the URL box and the website will display.

What I want to do is be able to reproduce the same on Win7 with IE8, for example.

[Another guy](https://serverfault.com/questions/257475/parallels-how-to-see-a-mac-hosted-website-from-windows/285203#285203) on Server Fault has done it successfully, here but I can't.

On Mac, I've done this:

```
ifconfig -a  

vnic0 10.211.55.2
```

On Windows 7, I tried this

```
 C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

10.211.55.2 mysite
```

What am I missing?

Comment: @JdeBP thanks for the flag WRT the OP needing to accept an answer, but there's nothing the mod team can do. We cannot force an accepted answers - *ever*. The only way this question will get an accept is if the user registers on both SF and SU, and links their accounts, to get ownership of the question back and then they can accept an answer themselves.

Comment: I suggested help, to a new user who had posted an acceptance _as another answer_, rather than force.

Answer (score 1):

if you use apache for your test web site, you need to bind (listen) first ip:port 10.211.55.2:80 in httpd.conf to make it work.

Add this row in httpd.conf (You can find first 127.0.0.1:80 and press new row after it)

```
Listen 10.211.55.2:80
```

Comment: @ling, if you want to re-gain ownership of this question (so you can accept an answer, comment, etc) then please note that you need to register on SF and SU and link your accounts.